# add javax.comm API on a mac

Tags: java, macos, javax.comm

I would like make an java app that communicates with a serial device(handheld scanner) so that the app is platform independent.
I have found a few code examples, and when I copy them into Eclipse it says that javax.comm.* is missing.
How do I install this on my Mac? 
And how do I add this library to my app so that the users does not have to install anything?

I want to able to give the users a jar file and the device, and they should be able to run it on windows/Mac/Linux without little or none configuration.

I found a download where I could download a javax.comm.jar file but the download included a win32comm.dll it dependented on some how - at least that was the fault I got when I added the jar file to my project.

```
Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no win32com in java.library.path
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Java Communications API.  You can get it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) but it won't help you.  The supported platforms are Solaris SPARC, Solaris x86, and Linux x86.

For Mac and Linux, if the serial port is already configured, you can open /dev/ttyS0, /dev/ttyS1, /dev/ttyS2, etc. as a file and read/write to it.  On Windows, if the serial port is already configured you can open "COM1", "COM2", etc. and read and write to it.

Unfortunately, javax.comm (as provided in the reference implementation) isn't cross-platform, so you'll have to either resort to bundling additional native libraries and supporting classes or use a platform-dependent way to configure the serial port.  On Windows, this could be the "mode" command, and on Mac/Linux, this could be the stty command.

Comment: So there is actually no platform independent way of communicating with the serialport???

Comment: I didn't say that.  Just that the reference implementation of javax.comm/Java Communications API is not platform independent.  In the J2SE API, there is no platform independent way of communicating with the serial port.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download). It doesn't use the `javax.comm` package, but it follows the same API (with some helpful additions).

E1: As it turns out, RXTX 2.0 does use the `javax.comm` package. You can find it on the same download page.