# ImportError: No Java Communications API implementation found

Tags: python, eclipse, arduino, jython

I have the following code:

```
import serial 

arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem14111') 
print(arduino.portstr)
```

And I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "/Users/miguelangelcallejonbosque/Documents/workspace/proyectp/principal/hola.py", line 2, in <module> 
   import serial 
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyserial-3.3-py2.7.egg/serial/__init__.py", line 31, in <module> 
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyserial-3.3-py2.7.egg/serial/serialjava.py", line 36, in <module> 
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyserial-3.3-py2.7.egg/serial/serialjava.py", line 30, in detect_java_comm 
ImportError: No Java Communications API implementation found
```

Can you help me solve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct form to open a serial port on arduino. try this

```
arduino = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyACM0',
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO,
bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
)
```

Please note that values depens by your board (these should work on arduino).
Also note that you must manage an serial.serialutil.SerialException exception.

[Here](https://github.com/Thecave3/serialplotter/blob/master/python/reader.py) you can find an example of working code (works on genuino UNO)

**UPDATE**
Figured out that the problem was a version incompatibility between library and jython

Comment: I still get the same error.

Maybe you have to see that I use mac os x?

Comment: This one is working on linux after library installation. [Have you installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228787/install-pyserial-mac-os-10-10) serial library on your mac?

Comment: This [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030975/add-javax-comm-api-on-a-mac) could help maybe. Please look at the correct answer.

Comment: Could you please give more information about your problem and your machine?

Comment: I try to connect arduino with python to port serial. My computer is a Mac Os, but I have done it with a windows and the error is the same

Comment: are changing every time that you plug your board in  the right port?

Comment: In windows for example is not tty but COMX (where x is an integer that defines your physical port)

Comment: Also seems the problem is on the import line, could you please show what version of python you're using (I don't know if serial is supported in jython).

Comment: Thanks to your contribution, I have been able to verify that running the code with the python interpreter works, but with the jython interpreter it does not work.

Comment: coud you please mark this as resolved (I have updated the answer)? Would be very apprecciate

Comment: Still not solved, because I need the serial with jython and only works well with python

Comment: You can create your own module using [sockets](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/socket.html), that seems your only option.